Raspberry pi zero(s) w from 2020 not working in 2024?
Description of a problem
I am trying to boot a raspbery pi zero W from 2020, but cannot get it working.
What I do

Burn the image to the SD card using raspberry imager
put the sd card in the slot
connect HDMI to my monitor
connect the power

What I see

the green diode is flashing initially for couple of minutes(?), then settles to constant green
the monitor diode i have it connected to it is flashing orange the same as when not connected to any input
I cannot see the device on wifi using the arp -a in powershell or nmap -v -sn 192.168.0.1/24 from another raspberry pi (pi4 circa 2020) connected to the wifi

Setup
My system used for setup

Lenovo Ideapad S340-IIL
Windows 10
Raspberry Pi imager v1.8.5

Monitor
Type: BENQ BL2410PT
Connection: VGA through mini HDMI to VGA connector
Router
TPLINK M7200
Power source

Power Bank (runs the Raspberry Pi4 fine)
official raspberry pi source

Images burning

official raspberry pi imager
set wifi and password in the imager setup
set hostname, username, and password
set identification through ssh keys (when setting up the raspberry pi 4, the user and password over ssh did not work)

What I tried

switch it off after 10 minutes, then start it again
burn different distributions (Bookworm, and the Bullseye legacy, from the selection in the official imager)
adding the wpa_supplicant.conf and creating ssh file in the bootfs (using gitbash on windows machine gitbash) when the booting did not work
tried two more raspberry pi zero W of roughly the same age, got the same result (this one run last in january okey, using the bullseye legacy image)

Solution(?)
Realized had a typo in the wpa_supplicant.conf. Had cntrl_interface instead of ctrl_interface.
Now I can connect to the device over ssh, thanks all for helping:)
wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=CZ
update_config=1


network={
  scan_ssid=1
  ssid="TP-Link_XXX"
  psk="XXXXXXX"
}


Have you tried a different SD card?

Also, have you tried an OS from the same age as the RPi - if that works then you can check if there is a firmware update needed to be able to run the latest OS. Just some ideas.

@AndrewMorton - Pi Zero has no updatable firmware to update :p

Your question is vague. You mention 2 OS  which are quite different (frankly I wouldn't even try Bookworm on such a limited Pi - certainly only Lite due to limited memory). I could suggest more details but there are already lots of posts which could help but without more detail of EXACTLY what you set in imager this would only be a repetition of the original documentation. If you want WiFi you NEED to specify country at the very least.

@Milliways Hello, thanks for reply, I tried the OS which were available from the selection using the official raspberry pi imager (first you select device, then the OS, so I assumed the options are filtered for the compatibility with the device), as for selecting the wifi country it is something I did put in the imager also, will update the post to have the screenshots of all the steps, is that better?

Bookworm Lite runs fine on a Pi Zero W - I just fired it up on a Zero W I haven't used in years. It takes quite a while for the first boot (because of resizing the root filesystem) but absolutely no issues running Bookworm Lite - as mentioned, I wouldn't bother trying to run the full version on such a toy

I don't see why it wouldn't -- I haven't plugged in a zero in a while as I never got any W models, but other Pi's I have running pretty much stock bookworm lite with a few things on top run on < 250 MiB RAM.  It would be an actual challenge to design and configure a basic GNU/Linux system to use much more than that sans GUI or significant server loads or whatever.

Vlad, check if any content is being written to the /var/log/journal directory, this would demonstrate the system booted to a running state with writable fs mounted, even if networking failed.  A wildcard is that you are using an HDMI -> VGA adapter, these have a record of failure here (especially if they do not provide their own supplementary power), so the fact it displays nothing doesn't mean the system isn't running, and the behavior of the green ACT led implies it is.

FWIW: I've got a couple of RPi 0W that run on 'bullseye' just fine - but I run them "headless" (i.e. the "Lite" version of the distro). I agree w/ @goldilocks that you should be able to run with a monitor, but it may require more effort. WRT 'bookworm': The "additional baggage" w/ bookworm is that the GUI is based on "Wayland" instead of X. Bottom line: I'd stick with 'bullseye' until you get everything working.

could be a bad monitor

@goldilocks Thank you, the /var.log/journal is not empty, contains two files: system.journal and system@75b-random numbers.journal. So this means the system boots, but I am not able to connect to wifi and also not able to connect to monitor, right?

@Seamus Okey I will go on with the bullseye. Now I am stuck with what to do, when I want to make the wifi connection working. I rember from last time, setting the wifi in the raspberry pi imager did not work, and needed to add the ssh and wpa_supplicant.conf to the bootfs folder. I am not sure if the wpa_supplicant is correct, it is confusing what parameters MUST be supplied. As I understand it, the country is importatn, then the ssid of the network, the password (not sure if this should be the literal password or its hash?),  is there something more to add?

@jsotola what is a "bad" monitor? the monitor is working with other computers, so you mean that the resolution is bad?

I think I solved connection to wifi, had a typo  in the wpa_supplicant, fixed it in the original post. Now it works with the bookworm version. Thanks to goldilocks Seamus Jaromanda Andrew Morton for helpful suggestions:)

@VladimirVinarsky I mean defective monitor ... your post does not say that the monitor works on other computers

please post an answer .... do not write the answer in the question

Glad to hear you got it working!  :)

@jsotola thank you for clarification:). I was not able to figure out where to label the post as solved as answered, so I wrote it in the question. Once I figure it out, will make it answered.
